# Migrating from dual boot to triple boot

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, grub, nvme

In my current setup, I have:

- 1 Crucial MX200 500GB SSD - Kali linux installed with grub bootloader, set as primary boot drive
- 1 Corsair Neutron XT 960GB SSD - Windows 7
- 1 Corsair Neutron XT 480GB SSD - Shared data drive

Since kali linux is set to the primary boot drive, the grub bootloader allows me to choose whether to boot to kali or windows 7.
However, I have gotten an additional intel 750 1.2TB PCIe NVME SSD and would like to install windows 10 on it while still maintaining kali as my primary boot drive.

1. Does grub recognize an NVME SSD drive?
2. Do I have to update and/or reinstall grub to make it triple boot?
3. What are the pitfalls I should look out for after installing windows 10 on the PCIe NVME SSD?

Comment: grub should work fine as of the recently released 2.02-beta3. 2.02-beta2 lacks this: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/commit/?id=9706066791b994a55fb2d3d532a86aa1fde2a457 so it will fail to find its modules et. al. if `--boot-directory` of `grub-install` (default: /boot) is on a partition of an NVMe drive

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a grub utility called **OS Prober** (you may already have this installed on kali, it's a common thing for it to be installed out of the box on Linux distributions, but it isn't always), this utility will detect windows 10 and add it to the grub bootloader menu when you re-generate the grub config (either **grub-mkconfig -o /path/to/grub.cfg** or **grub2-mkconfig -o /path/to/grub.cfg**) this should be all you have to do, (and then reboot to be able to select Windows 10 from grub) but in case your grub bootloader is not working anymore, you would have to re-install it from kali (**grub-install /dev/sdx**)